# How to handle effects with Pux?

Tags: purescript, purescript-pux

I'm just a beginner to the whole world of Purescript and Pux, so I'm a little confused as to where we handle effects.

Currently I'm modelling the effects in my type:

```
type State = { countries ∷ Maybe (Eff (random :: RANDOM) Countries) }
```

And then using that in my `foldp` function:

```
foldp (Request) state = { state, effects: [countries] }
```

Where `countries` is defined as:

```
countries = do
  response <- attempt $ get "/countries.json"
  let countries = either (Left <<< show) decode response
  pure $ Just $ Receive $ case shuffle <$> countries of
    Left _   → Nothing
    Right xs → Just xs
```

However at some point I need to *unwrap* the `RANDOM` effect from the type to be able to return it from my view: `State → HTML Event`.

Answer (score 1):

You simply don't do any side effects in the view. Lift the random effect in your foldp:

```
data Countries
data Event = Request | Received (Maybe Countries) | FetchError String

type State =  {countries :: Maybe Countries, error :: String}

type AppFx fx = (random :: RANDOM | fx)

foldp :: ∀ fx. FoldP State Event (AppFx fx)
foldp (FetchError msg) state = noEffects state{error = msg}
foldp (Received countries) state = noEffects state{countries = countries}
foldp Request state = {state, effects: pure countriesRequest}
  where
  countriesRequest = Just <$> do
    response <- attempt $ getCountries
    case response of
      Left errorMsg -> pure $ FetchError $ show errorMsg
      Right countries -> case shuffle countries of
          Left _ -> pure $ Received Nothing
          Right shuffleEff -> do
            shuffledCountries <- liftEff shuffleEff
            pure $ Received $ Just shuffledCountries

shuffle :: ∀ fx. Countries -> Either String (Eff (random :: RANDOM | fx) Countries)
shuffle = unsafeCrashWith "TODO"

getCountries :: ∀ fx. Aff fx Countries
getCountries = unsafeCrashWith "TODO"
```

Comment: Thanks @pete! Once I realised that effects only go in `foldp` then everything else follows.